# Rails5 - Undefined local variable but it's global

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am getting the following error in Rails:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<UserController:0x0000000458d708> Did you mean? @current_user
```

The code fragment corresponding to that error is:

```
authorize @current_user
```

As you can see, I clearly mean `@current_user` like the error message suggests, and I also use `@current_user` like the error message suggests. Why is Rails thinking I mean a local unexisting variable when I expect it to be global? The `authorize` method is from **Pundit**.

I added a print statement to verify if the global variable exists, and the following code effectively prints out a valid User:

```
p @current_user
authorize @current_user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Pundit, you must define `current_user` (or `pundit_user`): https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/lib/pundit.rb#L270

When you do `authorize @current_user`, that is assuring that the `current_user` can perform actions on `@current_user` using the `UserPolicy`.

Comment: This was the cause of the problem, thanks! Will accept in 6 minutes